# How to re-use a py Serial Port connection between script execution

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I have a python script that is run over SSH on a Raspberry Pi

It opens up multiple serial ports on the Pi, sends a command to the devices, then returns the results.

It is going to be run many times in succession (with different commands), so ideally I want to re use the open Serial port, rather than opening the port, running the command and closing the port with each execution.

Is there a way to open the ports separately to the script execution, and when the script is executed some how re purpose the open ports?

Comment: Is reopening the ports actually a lengthy enough operation that you need to worry about it?  The only way you'd be able to do this is to have a long-running program that actually has the ports open, and a separate interface program that talks to it (via a socket or pipe, probably).

Comment: @jasonharper yeah, thats what i thought.  Probably isn't worth worrying about, just a a noob at this, so was wondering if there was something I was missing.